# "Parfor" : Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab, dimension, mismatch, parfor

Please, I wrote the code below, and it works perfectly, but it takes about 6 hours.  So I was suggested to use `parfor` to reduce the time. But then I faced the error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch", and it doesn't appear immediately; it takes 2 hours then I got the error message after finishing all the iteration numbers.

So I would greatly appreciate your support! By the way, I just put `parfor ind1=1:720;` instead of `for`!

```
lon_rs=(reshape(l2aRS.clon_RS,3560*2000,1));
lat_rs=(reshape(l2aRS.clat_RS,3560*2000,1));
RSsig0=(reshape(l2aRS.sig0_RS,3560*2000,1));
RS_s0=zeros(720,360);
QS_s0=zeros(720,360);
I=ceil(2*(lon_rs));
J=ceil(2*(lat_rs+90));
K=ceil(2*(l1cQS.clon_QS));
L=ceil(2*(l1cQS.clat_QS+90));

for ind1=1:720;

    ind1

    for ind2=1:360;

        indsRS=find((I==ind1) &(J==ind2) &(RSsig0~=0));
        len_temp1=length(indsRS);

        if (len_temp1>0);
            len_RS(ind1,ind2)=len_temp1;           
            RS_s0(ind1,ind2)=median(RSsig0(indsRS));
        end;

        indsQS=find((K==ind1) &(L==ind2) &(l1cQS.sig_QS~=0));
        len_temp2=length(indsQS);

        if (len_temp2>0);
            len_QS(ind1,ind2)=len_temp2;
            QS_s0(ind1,ind2)=median(l1cQS.sig_QS(indsQS));
        end;

    end;

end;
```

Comment: Please edit your code (put it in code tags).

Comment: What do mean? I use this at the first time

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are using a loop it is recommended that you preallocate any variables that may change their size within the loop to their final size. If you want to use [`parfor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html) then you **must** preallocate `len_RS` and `len_QS`, like you did for `RS_s0` this will surely cut the run time of this code. It may also solve the "dimension mismatch" problem.